# ng-grid selected items don't bind

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a simple ng-grid

```
$scope.selectedSetups = [];
$scope.gridSetups = {
        data: 'setups',
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedSetups,
        multiSelect: true,
        showFilter: true,
        showColumnMenu: false,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field:'_id', displayName:' ', width: 0},
            {field:'name', displayName:'Name'},
            {field:'type', displayName:'Type'}]
};
```

I populate this grid in edit screen, so I have to check the checkboxes that comes from REST api. But I cannot. Here is the code.

```
SetupService.getSetups(function(data, result) {
    if (result == 200) {                
        $scope.setups = data;
        //$scope.selectedSetups.push(data[1]); // *If I do that, that works but manupilation of selectedSetups at the bottom doesn't work*

        if($routeParams.id != null) {       
            RuleService.getRule($routeParams.id, function(rule, status) {
                if(status == 200){                  
                    $scope.rule = rule;                 
                    angular.forEach(rule.commandIdList, function(item, key) {                   
                        angular.forEach($scope.setups, function(setup, key) {                   
                            if(setup.id == item){                           
                                $scope.selectedSetups.push(setup);
                            }
                        }); 
                    });
                }else{

                }
            });                 
        }
    } else {
        //TODO: Alert
    }
});
```

What is wrong, why I cannot update my selected items array and show this correctly on ng-grid?

Comment: try to wrap `$scope.selectedSetups.push(setup);` with `$apply`

Comment: @MaximShoustin I tried that, that did not work out. $scope.$apply(function(){          
          $scope.selectedSetups.push(setup); 
         });

Comment: just for testing, have you tried to move this line `$scope.selectedSetups.push(data[1]); ` inside each of the 3  if statements. Just to verify that it get executed.

Comment: @klode yeah, that also doesnt work out

Comment: this might be a stupid comment but, are you sure that the ifs conditions are `true`. a console.log() in `if(setup.id == item){}` would be executed?

Comment: not stuid for sure, but i tried it all

Comment: so the console.log() is executed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54040/discussion-between-klode-and-yagiz-ozturk).

Comment: Have you tried using selectRow() or selectItem()? See the row selection example here: https://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#rowSelection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like that.

```
SetupService.getSetups(function(data, result) {
    if (result == 200) {                
        $scope.setups = data;   

        if($routeParams.id != null) {       
            RuleService.getRule($routeParams.id, function(rule, status) {
                if(status == 200){                          
                    $scope.rule = rule;     
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        angular.forEach(rule.commandIdList, function(item, key) {                   
                            angular.forEach($scope.setups, function(setup, key) {                   
                                if(setup.id == item){
                                    $scope.gridSetups.selectRow(key, true);
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },10);
                }else{

                }
            });                 
        }
        //calculateTypes(data);
    } else {
        //TODO: Alert
    }
});
```